# Can't login via display manager (only tty) after a fresh install of Xubuntu

Tags: partitioning, login, login-screen, display-manager

When installing *Xubuntu 16.04 LTS* over *Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS* I deleted every previous partition but `/home`.

Just to clarify, here is a snapshot of the situation before and after:

### Before

- `/` 10GB `ext4`
- `/home` 482GB `XFS`
- `swap` 8GB

### After

- `/` 20GB `ext2`
- `/boot` 500MB `ext2`
- `swap` 4096MB
- `/var` ~3GB `BtrFS`
- `/home` 482GB `XFS`

I've then created the same user but with different password (I don't think that's an issue, right?) but when the login prompt appears and I try to access the system, the screen turns black for a moment and then the login prompt appears again, with no errors at all.

If I switch to a `tty`[1-6] I'm able to login normally and everything seems fine.

My *0.02$* is that something is wrong with the display manager, but I'm not completely sure either about this, because if I try to login as a guest I'm not experiencing issues at all.

It's worth noting, though, that before I switched from *Gnome* to *Xubuntu* I was experiencing problems with the display manager, the screen flashed in and out for about a min and then a `tty` appeared in place of a graphical login user interface.

Sometimes I was able to manually `startx` and sometimes not (well, most of the times not).

This problem just popped out of nothing suddenly, but I was to change distro anyway, so I catch the chance, with no luck I have to say.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that some older configuration files in your `/home`are in conflict with the new system.

If you reinstall Ubuntu over a previous installation using your old username, and you have a separate `/home` partition, make sure that you delete all the `.abc` hidden **folders** (`.config`; `.local`; etc.) in your personal folder before installing Ubuntu (but you can manage to do this in order to get your system working). To do so, you can open the `/home` partition from your Live system, and let the hidden folders appear by pressing `CTRL+H` in your keyboard, so you can delete them.

If you delete the folders, when you boot your new Ubuntu installation, the necessary folders that the system needs should be created. If you are using the old username, the only things that aren´t automatically generated are the files which are in `/etc/skel`, but in your particular case, it should not be a problem, since you are reinstalling an Ubuntu 16.04 over another 16.04 (no matter if you are using Xubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME, or everything else). If you are unsure, you could copy manually the files from `/etc/skel` (which are hidden, so you have to press `CTRL+H` to see them) to your personal folder

So, the best thing you could do is to boot your Live Ubuntu and delete the hidden folders in your home.

If that doesn´t work, you can always reinstall Ubuntu using another username (just make sure not to format your `/home`). The older user folder will remain in your `/home` partition, so you can recover your files easily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the problem might be the hidden folders. Why is it so?

Comment: Because that hidden folders store configurations related to the OS and the desktop environment. Probably there are some older configurations from your old Ubuntu GNOME installation, that interfere with Xubuntu login. It's the most possible reason, since you say that you can get to login screen (so the problem gets reduced to user-level) and the OS logs in correcty via tty.

Comment: In the past, I suffered similar issues to yours, and I managed to fix them by deleting the hidden configuration folders.

Comment: Right, seems logic. Will leave feedback ASAP.